# How would I check if string is equal to a value in an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object called codes:

```
var codes = {
    code1: 'test1'
    code2: 'test2'
  }
```

And i want to check if it has a property and log the result to the console

```
if(input == what goes here)
{
   console.log("Has property")
}
```

Sorry if its a very obvious answer, I am pretty new to Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty()`:

```js
var codes = {
    code1: 'test1',
    code2: 'test2'
  }


console.log(codes.hasOwnProperty('code1'));
console.log(codes.hasOwnProperty('code2'));
console.log(codes.hasOwnProperty('code3'));
```

```
if(codes.hasOwnProperty(input)){

}
```